# Error while trying to use AWS-SDK in JsPolicy

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, jspolicy

I'm new to using JsPolicy and I'm trying to define a simple cluster policy to deny access on default namespaces. However, I'm having trouble getting the policy to work properly. Here's my policy YAML:

```
# policy.yaml
apiVersion: policy.jspolicy.com/v1beta1
kind: JsPolicy
metadata:
  name: "deny-default-namespace.company.tld"
spec:
  operations: ["CREATE"]
  resources: ["*"]
  scope: Namespaced
  javascript: |
    import * as AWS from "aws-sdk"
    if (request.namespace === "default") {
      deny("Creation of resources within the default namespace is not allowed!");
    }
```

The following error is displayed while trying to use aws-sdk to get the image from ECR to verify:

`Error from server: admission webhook "deny-default-namespace.company.tld" denied the request: Uncaught ReferenceError: setTimeout is not defined.`

The policy works fine when I remove the import statement for the AWS SDK, but I need to use it for my use case. I can't seem to find any relevant documentation on this issue. Can anyone help me understand why this error is occurring and how to resolve it?

Comment: jspolicy doesnt need aws-sdk. you should remove it

Answer (score 0):

You had an invalid reference to aws-sdk. remove that line. it should work.
Or Use the below snippet

```
# policy.yaml
apiVersion: policy.jspolicy.com/v1beta1
kind: JsPolicy
metadata:
  name: "deny-default-namespace.company.tld"
spec:
  operations: ["CREATE"]
  resources: ["*"]
  scope: Namespaced
  javascript: |
    if (request.namespace === "default") {
      deny("Creation of resources within the default namespace is not allowed!");
    }
```